# How to SFINAE using concepts on member non-template function of a template struct?

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

### Background

I'm writing an object pool. I would like to provide one constructor which just accepts the count of elements to default construct. There is a [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/default_initializable) for that already, I would like to try to use C++20 feature for this.

### Code

```
template <typename T, std::size_t capacity>
class object_pool {
/*
    storage for uninitialized objects
    used flags
    size
    etc...
*/

public:
    ??? object_pool(std::size_t count = capacity) {
        /* initialization */
    }

};
```

I can SFINAE the conventional way, which would look like:

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>>
object_pool(std::size_t count = capacity) {
  /*...*/
}
```

### Question

Can concepts be used to SFINAE on member function of template class/struct? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a requires expression after the signature

```
object_pool(std::size_t count = capacity) requires std::default_initializable<T> {
  /*...*/
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/4W3P8z7so)

Comment: I did not know that concepts can be put on non-template entities. I guess that way they would be useless ... Thanks!

Comment: @Incomputable concepts are versatile. You can also use them as boolean values, like `if (std::default_initializable<T>) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the info. One last question: can I put noexcept check on T on either side of the requires clause?

Comment: @Incomputable do you mean to check if `T` has a noexcept function, or to mark the constructor as noexcept?

Comment: I would like to make the constructor of object_pool noexcept if the constructor of T is noexcept. [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) really needs to be updated to include concepts.

Comment: Yeah requires clauses are missing in a lot of places in the documentation. The `noexcept` specifier has to go before the requires clause: `object_pool(std::size_t count = capacity)  noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>) requires std::default_initializable<T>`